# how to access form input elements in get request for node

Tags: node.js, get, form-submit

In my html in a node application I have a form as follows:

```
<form action="/getRoute" method="get">
           <input type="hidden" name='a' value=<%- array1[0].element1 %>>
           <input type="hidden" name='b' value=<%- array2[0].element2 %>>
           <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I click submit, the getRoute route is executed successfully (confirmed by console.log statement) - however, I cannot access the values of the hidden input fields by req.body - would anyone know how I can access these, or alternatively use another html element to pass data into the route?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that you these inputs are passed via the URL and can be accessed by `req.query.a` and `req.query.b` - it's not ideal to send sensitive data via get requests since the URL can be seen.